# select one table from two tables with same primary key but different value?

Tags: mysql

```
Table1           Table2

id  | name       id   | name
-----------      ------------
2   | A           2   |  E   
4   | B           3   |  F
6   | C           4   |  G
8   | D           5   |  H
```

Output:

```
Id  |  name
------------
2   |  A *** E
4   |  B *** G
6   |  C *** EMPTY
8   |  D *** EMPTY
3   |  EMPTY *** F
5   |  EMPTY *** H
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.name, 
       t2.name
from table1 t1
  full outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.name is distinct from t2.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(a.id, b.id), case when a.value is not null and b.value is not null then a.value + '***' + b.value
```

else coalesce(a.value,b.value) end from table_1 a full outer join table_2 b on a.id = b.id